# How to invoke a subscriber's callback periodically?

Tags: ros, rospy, callbacks, message-filter, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I would like to sample messages from my sensors' topics every 15 seconds (mostly) synchronically, using [message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer](http://docs.ros.org/api/message_filters/html/python/#message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer). Is that any possible way to register a callback, that will be invoked, for example, every 15 seconds? I've already check out [rospy.Timer](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/rospy/html/rospy.timer-module.html), but it seems to be not an appropriate way in my case.

My basic code:

```
def callback(sensor1, sensor2):
     #write messages into csv
 

def listener():

    sensor0 = message_filters.Subscriber("/sensor0/topic", Int32)
    sensor1 = message_filters.Subscriber("/sensor1/topic", Int32)
   
    ts = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([sensor0,sensor1], 10, 0.1)
    ts.registerCallback(callback)
    rospy.spin()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293266/how-to-invoke-a-subscriber%27s-callback-periodically?/) by [kolner](https://answers.ros.org/users/35520/kolner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A callback is an event driven routine. As such, by design, you cannot call it periodically.
Just store the latest value in a class member and use a `rospy.Timer` to periodically take the latests values from those.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1